# Why is this file not deleted?

Tags: linux, bash, exit-code

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following case will leave the file "lock" present on the file system.

file `script`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
run-parts sub &> /dev/null
```

file `sub/subscript`:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Exit if another job is running.
[ -e ./lock ] && exit 0

trap "rm -f ./lock; exit" 0 1 2 5 15

touch ./lock
echo "test"
```

When now running `run-parts --report .` in the folder where `script` is, why does it exit with the file `lock` present?

**What I think it should do:**

1) look for runnable scripts in the current folder (finds `script`)

2) it will run `script` and inside it will run another run-parts instance which finds the script `sub/subscript` and run this one

3) the file `sub/subscript` will create the file `lock` and **should** remove it again when signals 0, 1, 2, 5 or 15 occur.

**What I found out so far:**

1) Removing `&> /dev/null` will remove the lock file

2) Removing `--report` will also remove the lock file

However in my case, these two resolutions are not an option, as I am not the maintainer of the code.

From what I understand, neither of the mentioned signals will be triggered. Why is this?

OS: Debian Jessie

Comment: Instead of `&> /dev/null`, try redirecting to a file, like `&> /tmp/out` and see if the output contains anything useful?

Comment: Unfortunately the lockfile is still present and an empty file `/tmp/out` is created.

Comment: I suspect `trap` isn't getting called under certain circumstances.  It helps if you can put an additional `touch /tmp/trap.stat` inside the `trap` code to verify if that is indeed the case.  If `trap` calling is the issue, it could be an OS specific problem.

Comment: I have modified the trap line from `trap "rm -f ./lock; exit" 0 1 2 5 15` to `trap "touch ./trapfile; rm -f ./lock; exit" 0 1 2 5 15`. The specified "trapfile" is not being created when running the command (`run-parts --report .`)

Comment: Maybe you should handle more signals, maybe SIGPIPE (13). see `man 7 signal` for more signals.

Comment: You should select the answer or ask more.

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Exit if another job is running.
[ -e ./lock ] && exit 0
```

First, change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` since this is a bash question.  You are probably running a flavor of Linux that links /bin/sh to /bin/bash, but that's not certain.  Next, if you run this, and the lock file exists, it will exit and leave the file.

```
trap "rm -f ./lock; exit" 0 1 2 5 15

touch ./lock
echo "test"
```

Then the above is ran, if lock wasn't there.  You touch the file, echo test, and remove it.  You've not mentioned if you've see a "test" echoed back yet.  It seems to be working as intended.